# doesn't support architecture 'arm64' doesn't support architecture -armhf

Tags: files, 32-bit, chromebook, arm, itunes

i need a vendor to compile an ARM64 and  an Armhf repository for my 32 bit chromebook. it won't install wine or itunes 32 bit on my chromebook

Comment: Wine is used to run Windows (Intel based) programs, so it will not run on ARM architecture anyway. Itunes, AFAIK, is a closed source software developed by Apple, so you should ask Apple for it.

Comment: "i need a vendor to compile"  then why ask us? :)  and that is never going to happen.

Comment: Please edit your question and add details what Ubuntu has to do with it. Do you want to cross-compile from Ubuntu Linux to ChromeOS?